# Taking local wordpress site to remote location

Tags: php, wordpress, web

I am not an expert Wordpress developer, and I am having the following problem while taking my website, designed locally using Wordpress and MAMP, to the remote location where it should be.

When I transfer all content to the designated remote location, I can see the content of the page, but graphics, CSS and images are not loaded. Looking at the developer console on Chrome I see a lot of error along the lines of:

GET https://localhost:8888/icdm/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

That seems to happen for content in wp-includes and wp-content directories.

That is the address I used locally when designing the website, so clearly there must be some reference to localhost that I must have missed. I have checked that files and folders have adequate permissions, and trying to scan wordpress config files I can't see any reference to localhost.

Thank you to anyone willing to help with this issue, I am kind of stuck and cannot progress.

Comment: If I remind you that all LIVE web servers run on PORT 80 and not port 8888 will it help you see the error

Comment: Good old Wordpress stores the domain you installed it into in its database. Check the Wordpress site to see how to change the database to sort this out

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I solved my issue looking at the link to where this was already answered.